# Here Maps Add Info bubble to map when using Vue

Tags: vuejs2, here-api

Trying to add info bubble to map in my heremap vue component (ive taken bits from https://developer.here.com/blog/showing-a-here-map-with-the-vue.js-javascript-framework and also https://developer.here.com/blog/develop-a-cross-platform-desktop-maps-application-with-electron-vue.js-and-here)

I have a couple of methods on my component(mostly copied over from the here docs)

```
methods:{  
        AddMarkerToGroup(group, location, icon) {                       

            var marker = new H.map.Marker({ lat: location.Latitude, lng: location.Longitude }, { icon: icon });
            marker.setData(location.Data);
            group.addObject(marker);
        },         
        addMarkersToMap(locations,defaultIconUrl) {
            var scale = window.devicePixelRatio;                
            var icon = new H.map.Icon(defaultIconUrl, { size: { w: 45 * scale, h: 50 * scale } });

            var group = new H.map.Group();                
            this.map.addObject(group);                               
            group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {

                // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
                // for all objects that it contains
                var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
                    // read custom data
                    content: evt.target.getData()
                });
                // show info bubble                    
                this.ui.addBubble(bubble);                                 
            }, false);                

            var addmarker = this.AddMarkerToGroup;
            locations.forEach(function (location) {                    

                addmarker(group, location, icon);
            });                        
        }`
```

However i cant get the info bubble to display when the map marker is clicked. this.ui is undefined in the context of this event listener.  Outside the event listener it isn't undefined. ui is defined in the mounted component event:

```
mounted: function() {
        // Initialize the platform object:           
        var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
        let defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers({
            tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
            ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
        });
        this.map = new H.Map(
        this.$refs.map,
        defaultLayers.normal.map,
        {pixelRatio: pixelRatio, zoom: 5, center: { lat: 54.00366, lng: -2.547855} });
        let behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map));
        this.ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.map, defaultLayers);
        this.LoadMapLocations();                      
    },
```

Does anybody know how to get info bubble to display?

Comment: ive tried to create reference to this outside of the event listener and then use this reference inside but then i get no errors on console - good but the info marker still doesn't appear.

Comment: Have you declared ui like this data: () => ({ ui: null }) ? If yes, then please share your entire js code so that we can assist you better.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f7hjaw5q/ - the javascript section contains the entire javascript of my HereMap.vue component. Too large to post in comment. --left in alert i was using for debugging
 Thanks

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport are there any plans for a vue npm library for here maps?

Comment: Hey @JimmyShoe, have you seen my tutorial that includes InfoBubbles with Vue? https://developer.here.com/blog/searching-for-points-of-interest-with-the-here-places-api-in-a-vue.js-application

Comment: Thanks @NicRaboy that looks like what I'm looking for.  Would be great if there was a specific Vue section on the here websites as finding some things is a bit of a chore. I'd read some of your other posts but didn't see this one.

Comment: I'm still having issues... Maybe because I am add markers to a group, I'll spend some time following along the blog post to see if it works that way for me.

Comment: Thanks for help  - i was able to narrow down my issue to not including the here maps style sheet ooops. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1533195059" />

Comment: Glad you got it working! I encourage you to subscribe to the RSS feed so you don't miss out on content :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These blogs were really useful:

- https://developer.here.com/blog/showing-a-here-map-with-the-vue.js-javascript-framework
- https://developer.here.com/blog/develop-a-cross-platform-desktop-maps-application-with-electron-vue.js-and-here
- https://developer.here.com/blog/searching-for-points-of-interest-with-the-here-places-api-in-a-vue.js-application

**My problem was I forgot to add the reference to the stylesheet.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1533195059" />
```

**dont forget to add the script files:**

```
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-places.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

My HereMap.vue component in full:

```
`<template>
   <div class="here-map">
        <div ref="map" v-bind:style="{ width: width, height: height }"></div>
    </div>
</template>`

<script>
export default {
    name: "HereMap",
    data() {
        return {
            map: {},
            platform: {},
            router:{},
            geocoder:{},
            directions:[],
            ui: null
        }
    },
    props: {
        appId: String,
        appCode: String,
        lat: String,
        lng: String,
        width: String,
        height: String            
    },
    created: function() { 
        this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
            "app_id": this.appId,
            "app_code": this.appCode,
            'useHTTPS': true,
            'useCIT': true
        }); 
        this.router = this.platform.getRoutingService();
        this.geocoder = this.platform.getGeocodingService();
    },
    mounted: function() {
        // Initialize the platform object:           
        var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
        let defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers({
            tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
            ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
        });
        this.map = new H.Map(
        this.$refs.map,
        defaultLayers.normal.map,
        {pixelRatio: pixelRatio, zoom: 5, center: { lat: 54.00366, lng: -2.547855} });
        let behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map));
        this.ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.map, defaultLayers);
        this.LoadMapLocations();                      
    },               
    methods:{  
        AddMarkerToGroup(group, location, icon) {                       
            console.log(location);
            var marker = new H.map.Marker({ lat: location.Latitude, lng: location.Longitude }, { icon: icon });
            marker.setData(location.Data);
            group.addObject(marker);
        },         
        addMarkersToMap(locations,defaultIconUrl) {
            var scale = window.devicePixelRatio;                
            var icon = new H.map.Icon(defaultIconUrl, { size: { w: 45 * scale, h: 50 * scale } });

            var group = new H.map.Group();                
            this.map.addObject(group);
            var self = this;  
            var position;                             
            group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {                    
                position = evt.target.getPosition();

                // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
                // for all objects that it contains
                var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
                    // read custom data
                    content: evt.target.getData()                       
                });
                // show info bubble                                       
                self.ui.addBubble(bubble);                    
            }, false);                

            var addmarker = this.AddMarkerToGroup;
            locations.forEach(function (location) {                    

                addmarker(group, location, icon);
            });                                                        
        },                        
        LoadMapLocations(){
            let locations = [
                { Name: "Wolverhampton" , Latitude:52.5914143, Longitude: -2.1496674, Data: "wolverhampton meeting" },
                { Name: "London" , Latitude:51.5048147, Longitude: -0.121162, Data: "london meeting" },
                { Name: "Manchester" , Latitude:53.4757539, Longitude: -2.2791187, Data: "manchester meeting" }                    
            ];                
            this.addMarkersToMap(locations,"https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33622.png");                                                             
        },
        ZoomToLocation(lat,long,zoom){
            console.log("zoom to location ");
            this.map.setCenter({ lat: lat, lng: long });
            this.map.setZoom(zoom); 
        }            
    }        
};
```